# Why JUnit not calling explicit no arg ctor in same package as test

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception

Simple JUnit test, in same package as code under test, but in different source (src) folder. NullPointerException thrown since it appears that my JUnit code is not invoking my no-arg ctor in source under test. No syntax errors. Why is my dao null?

Debugged, and not hitting expected ctor.

```
// In src folder:

package com.dao.pkg;
public class PTests {
  Processor p;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DAO dao = new MockDAO();
    p = new Processor(dao);  // dao is null!!!!
  }
...
}

// And in the test src folder:

package com.dao.pkg;
public class MockDAO implements DAO {
  public MockDAO() {
    System.out.println("testing that ctor is being hit");
  }
   ...
}
```

dao object should be created (nonNull), and is not (is Null)

Comment: `dao` can't be null if you explicitly assigned a newly created object to it, so there must be something else going on here. Can you share the code for `Processor` and the stacktrace?

Comment: The invocation of creating a MockDAO is failing, returning null, so sending null to Processor ctor. Issue is prior to invoking Processor ctor.

Comment: No. A constructor cannot "return" null. Either it constructs an object, or it throws an exception. Post the exact and complete stack trace, and the actual code.

Comment: have you re-compiled your code before running it? is this within an IDE? did you save the files you altered last before re-running?

Comment: ehm... why exactly are you instantiating MockDao in your 'production' code? All your test code should be under the test package.

Comment: I understand ctors don't have "return"s. I'm merely trying to explain the issue. Using Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0), and have restarted IDE. Never said I was mocking in production. JUnit source and Mock source exist in same package, but reside in different src folders in the IDE. Code shown here is a simplified version exhibiting exact behavior of issue.

Comment: But despite being asked twice to provide the actual code and the stack trace, you still refuse to do so. That's what would allow us to understand and explain what the issue really is. Why don't you do it? That's the third time now.

Comment: @frododot yes, you did say that. "Simple JUnit test, in same package as code under test, but in different source (src) folder. " It's right there, in that sentence. You are trying to write a unit test in a package that is meant for your actual code that you should be testing.

Comment: @Stultuske that's standard testing practice. You put production code in src/main/java, and test code in src/test/java. The test class for com.foo.bar.ProductionService is the class com.foo.bar.ProductionServiceTest. There's nothing wrong with that. What is wrong is to not post the code and the stack trace.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I get that, but out of his post I understand that he has his: " ... = new MockDAO();" in src/main/java", "In same package as code under test but in different source (src) folder"

Comment: Problem solved: no changes to syntax / packages / folders needed. Maven update was required, as project apparently went stale. Closing.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Maven (or Gradle) update was necessary on this apparently stale project. Problem solved.